# HTML && CSS how can i delete unused place of a div

Tags: html, css

Here is the my code 
How can i add the text near by Sign up window.Because it seems that empty place piece of class of "signupWindow" and even it looks empty , i can not add something.When i change the div to span and everything goes crazy. Is there a way to delete that unused place of that ?
Here is the my code

```css
.avatar{
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    margin-left: 30%;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.signupWindow{
    
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 870px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 340px;
    background-color:cornflowerblue;/*rgba(20, 20, 31,0.4);*/
    border-radius: 5%;
}
.textAreas{
    color: white;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.textAreas input{
    
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.bottomplace{
    height: 10px;
    
}
.bottom1{
    margin-top: 65px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
   float: left;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.bottom1:hover{
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.wifiimg{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Anasayfa</title>
    <?php include("../Banner/banner.php") ?>
        <link href="container.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <div class="signupWindow">
            <img src="avatar.png" class="avatar">
              <div class="textAreas">
                  
                 E mail:<br><input type="email" value=""><br>
                 <br>Username:<br><input type="text" value=""><br>
                <br> Password:<br><input type="text" value=""><br>
                <br> Password again<input type="text" value=""><br>
                 <input type="submit" value="Sign up">                        
              </div>
        </div>
            <div class="maintext">
        <h1>HEADER</h1>
            <p> SOME TEXT You know how sometimes you see Latin-looking placeholder text in documents? Well, you can generate that yourself in Word. But before I explain how, why might you wish to do so in the first place?

The most common and obvious reason is to see what a particular template or font looks like when it is applied to a body of text. Rather than copying and pasting text from another source, or typing it anew, you can save time by using a built-in macro.

Another reason to want to generate a great deal of text quickly is to get an idea of how a published report or book might look when there are 200 pages of it to bind and handle.

Here’s how you do it:

</p>
    </div>
        <div class="bottomplace">
             <div class="bottom1">
                <img src="wifi.png" class="wifiimg">
            <h>Basşık</h>
            <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfsadf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfas</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom1">
                <img src="wifi.png" class="wifiimg">
            <h>Basşık</h>
            <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfsadf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfas</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom1">
                <img src="wifi.png" class="wifiimg">
            <h>Basşık</h>
            <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfsadf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfas</p>
            </div>
            
        </div>
         

        
    </body>




</html>
```

Comment: Please don't use all caps unless you're using an acronym like HTML. It reads as yelling in some cultures. Also read [ask] regarding writing good titles.

Comment: Sorry about that , i will be more carefull next time

Comment: You can [edit] your question now; no need to wait for next time :).

Answer (score 0):

What if you change height to auto?

```
.signupWindow{

    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 870px;
    height: auto;
    width: 340px;
    background-color:cornflowerblue;/*rgba(20, 20, 31,0.4);*/
    border-radius: 5%;
}
```

Also, it's better using percentages instead of the pixels. Like "Margin-left: 870px" change it to %.

Comment: I have tried that it makes height automaticly untill last attribute

Answer (score 0):

With well-planned structure, you can achieve this. I hope you want to keep the content left and sing in form right to achieve something like first you have to make the structure like this

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="left"> 
   <!-- Add your left content here -->
  </div>

  <div class="right"> 
    <!-- Add your right content here (signup form) -->
  </div>
</div>
```

then add the css like below. this code structured your left and right div like table columns

```
.main-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Then add your content into left div and right div.

Answer (score 0):

I added few code based your code, you can try this does meet your need.

```css
/* new added */
.my-class {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.avatar{
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    margin-left: 30%;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

/* new added */
.maintext {
    margin: 0 100px;
}

.signupWindow{
    flex-shrink: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    /*margin-left: 870px;*/
    margin-right: 130px; /* new added */
    height: 500px;
    width: 340px;
    background-color:cornflowerblue;/*rgba(20, 20, 31,0.4);*/
    border-radius: 5%;
}
.textAreas{
    color: white;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.textAreas input{
    
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.bottomplace{
    height: 10px;
    
}
.bottom1{
    margin-top: 65px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
   float: left;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.bottom1:hover{
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.wifiimg{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Anasayfa</title>
    <?php include("../Banner/banner.php") ?>
        <link href="container.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="my-class">       
            <!-- changed the order of <div class="maintext"> and <div class="signupWindow">  -->
           <div class="maintext">
            <h1>HEADER</h1>
                <p> SOME TEXT You know how sometimes you see Latin-looking placeholder text in documents? Well, you can generate that yourself in Word. But before I explain how, why might you wish to do so in the first place?

                The most common and obvious reason is to see what a particular template or font looks like when it is applied to a body of text. Rather than copying and pasting text from another source, or typing it anew, you can save time by using a built-in macro.

                Another reason to want to generate a great deal of text quickly is to get an idea of how a published report or book might look when there are 200 pages of it to bind and handle.

                Here’s how you do it:

                </p>
            </div>


            <div class="signupWindow">
                <img src="avatar.png" class="avatar">
                  <div class="textAreas">
                      
                     E mail:<br><input type="email" value=""><br>
                     <br>Username:<br><input type="text" value=""><br>
                    <br> Password:<br><input type="text" value=""><br>
                    <br> Password again<input type="text" value=""><br>
                     <input type="submit" value="Sign up">                        
                  </div>
            </div>
 
        </div>

        <div class="bottomplace">
             <div class="bottom1">
                <img src="wifi.png" class="wifiimg">
            <h>Basşık</h>
            <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfsadf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfas</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom1">
                <img src="wifi.png" class="wifiimg">
            <h>Basşık</h>
            <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfsadf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfas</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom1">
                <img src="wifi.png" class="wifiimg">
            <h>Basşık</h>
            <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfsadf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfas</p>
            </div>
            
        </div>
         

        
    </body>




</html>
```